# crackling/clicking sound from agricultural field

Tags: identification, mystery-sound

I was cycling by an agricultural field that had cut plants in it in southern Germany (near the Max-Planck for Or ithology) last summer. The remaining stems seemed brown and dried up. As a light drizzle began I started to hear crackling sounds come from the cut stems all over the field.

The sounds continued even after the light drizzle passed. Sadly, this was a chance observation where i didn't manage to record the sounds.

Does anyone have *any* idea of what these sounds ar called, and when it occurs. I've gone by many fields with whole and cut plants but have never heard this kind of sound and would greatly appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cool that you heard this! I have heard similar cracking in corn fields in Indiana. I think what these crackles are are sounds produced by tiny fractures as the plant grows. Here is an article about such crackling:

https://cropwatch.unl.edu/2016/can-you-hear-corn-grow-yes